What do I do if my hard drive keeps filling up?
I have a 461GB hard drive. For some reason, it keeps filling up until I have no more space left. I tried turning off hibernation. It helped for a while, but the disk space got filled up eventually. I frequently clean my temp folder and empty my recycle bin, but the C drive quickly fills up again. I tried right clicking on Local Disk, pressing "properties" and cleaning system files in disk cleanup, but that did not help. How do I stop my hard drive from constantly filling up?

What is on your hard drive? Name the partitions and their purpose.

Have you used the program called WinDirStat? It's a popular program that visualizes directories and files taking up most storage. Can be handy in this case.
